# Cast function parameter type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Forcibly change a functions parameter type by casting itself.

It looked like

```
(<number>foo)(1)
```

Where

```
function foo( v : string )
```

Comment: In TS, you can't "forcibly change" the type of anything. What you can do is to tell the compiler that it should **think of** a particular value as a particular type. That is called "type assertion".

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the function param types but you can cast ([type assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)) the param you're passing to it to `any`:

```
function fn(obj: string) {
    ...
}

fn(1 as any);
```

But you can make the function more generic:

```
function fn(obj: string | number) {
    ...
}

fn(1);
fn("str");
```

You can also use generics:

```
function fn<T>(obj: T) {
    ...
}

fn(1);
fn("str");
```

Comment: The word "cast" is nowhere to be found in the TS docs or specs.

Comment: @torazaburo from the [basic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html): `"A type assertion is like a type cast in other languages, but performs no special checking or restructuring of data"`.

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, that quote is best interpreted as saying that in TypeScript we do **not** use the term "cast". "Cast" as used in other languages normally means that I am **forcibly changing** the type, for example, casting an integer to a pointer in C. Casting in this sense is not possible in TypeScript, where the `<type> value` or `value as type` syntax is simply telling the compiler to **think of** `value` as being of type `type`, and this will only work if the types are compatible. To avoid confusion, I still think it's better to avoid the word "cast".

Comment: @torazaburo You may interpret it as you wish, but the bottom line is that it's the same in most cases, if there would be a difference between `<string> obj` and `obj as string` (like in C# for example) then I'd be fine with differentiating the two, but that's not the case. Another point is that `"cast"` can be a verb, but `"type assertion"` can't (assert can, but it's not as clear)